# In Python 2.7 why are strings written faster in text mode than in binary mode?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io, cpython

The following example script writes some strings to a file using either `"w"`, text, or `"wb"`, binary mode:

```
import itertools as it
from string import ascii_lowercase
import time

characters = it.cycle(ascii_lowercase)
mode = 'w'
# mode = 'wb'  # using this mode takes longer to execute
t1 = time.clock()
with open('test.txt', mode) as fh:
    for __ in xrange(10**7):
        fh.write(''.join(it.islice(characters, 0, 50)))
t2 = time.clock()
print 'Mode: {}, time elapsed: {:.2f}'.format(mode, t2 - t1)
```

With Python 2, using `"w"` mode I found it executes in `24.89 +/- 0.02 s` while using `"wb"` it takes `25.67 +/- 0.02 s` to execute. These are the specific timings for three consecutive runs for each mode:

```
mode_w  = [24.91, 24.86, 24.91]
mode_wb = [25.68, 25.64, 25.69]
```

I'm surprised by these results since Python 2 stores its strings anyway as binary strings, so neither `"w"` nor `"wb"` need to perform any encoding work. Text mode on the other hand needs to perform additional work such as [checking for line endings](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#open):

> The default is to use text mode, which may convert `'\n'` characters to a platform-specific representation on writing and back on reading.

So if anything I'd expect text mode `"w"` to take longer than binary mode `"wb"`. However the opposite seems to be the case. Why is this?

---

<sup>Tested with CPython 2.7.12</sup>

Comment: It would be interesting to time "wb" with byte strings. You could remove the join completely and just rewrite the same line over and over to focus just on the writing part.

Comment: @Chris Using a t-test gives a p-value of < 5 ppm, which suggests that the difference is significant.

Comment: @tdelaney I just benchmarked this case by writing `ascii_lowercase` directly over and over again. The timings I obtained are `wb = [3.13, 3.16, 3.15]` and `w = [2.22, 2.19, 2.23]`.

Comment: Are you linux or windows? I assume windows, using `time.clock` for high resolution. Linux time.clock is different.

Comment: With tweaks for linux I got "w" 4.19, 4.24, 4.46 and "wb" at 5.08, 4.97, 4.89. Still a significant difference.

Comment: It would be interesting to look at the source, but I haven't time at the moment.

Comment: @tdelaney I'm on Linux, in what way is `time.clock` different for the two OS? In any case, the docs mention that *"[...] this is the function to use for benchmarking Python or timing algorithms."* So it seems to be appropriate for these benchmarking purposes. I'd also like to look at the source code but I haven't found the relevant parts yet. I'll post an update if I find something.

Comment: `time.clock` doesn't include time you spend in I/O (depends on where in the I/O you are) or in a wait state. So it may be a better measurement here. I tend to worry about I/O and response time so favor time.time() day to day. But you've got a good point.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code for [`file.write`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.12/Objects/fileobject.c#L1799) reveals the following difference between [binary mode](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.12/Objects/fileobject.c#L1811) and [text mode](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.12/Objects/fileobject.c#L1817):

```
if (f->f_binary) {
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s*", &pbuf))
        return NULL;
    s = pbuf.buf;
    n = pbuf.len;
}
else {
    PyObject *text;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &text))
        return NULL;

    if (PyString_Check(text)) {
        s = PyString_AS_STRING(text);
        n = PyString_GET_SIZE(text);
    }
```

Here `f->f_binary` is set when the mode for `open` includes `"b"`. In this case Python constructs an auxiliary buffer object from the string object and then gets the data `s` and length `n` from that buffer. I suppose this is for compatibility (generality) with other objects that support the buffer interface.

Here [`PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s*", &pbuf)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.12/Python/getargs.c#L840) creates the corresponding [buffer object](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.12/Objects/abstract.c#L680). This operation requires additional compute time while when working with text mode, Python simply parses the argument [as an Object (`"O"`)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.12/Python/getargs.c#L1234) at almost no cost. Retrieving the data and length via

```
s = PyString_AS_STRING(text);
n = PyString_GET_SIZE(text);
```

is also performed [when the buffer is created](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v2.7.12/Python/getargs.c#L846).

This means that when working in binary mode there's an additional overhead associated with creating an auxiliary buffer object from the string object. For that reason the execution time is longer when working in binary mode.